# Is it correct to use "wattage" and "amperage" instead of "power" and "current"?

Tags: terminology, units

Is it legitimate to call the name of an electrical quantity with the name of the unit of that quantity by adding the `-age` suffix to it?

Examples:

```
1. Power                --> Wattage  (Rarely used.)
2. Current              --> Amperage (Rarely used.)
3. Potential Difference --> Voltage  (Frequently used.)
4. Resistance           --> Ohmage   (I made up this one.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some concepts, like "power" can have multiple different associated units depending on the context. For instance, power can be Watts, Kilowatt-Hours, Joules, etc.  By using "wattage" in that situation you are being slightly more specific about the units used.

In general though, most times it's completely interchangeable, since the units and the concept are tied together - potential difference is always measured in volts, so "voltage" is perfectly acceptable.  Current is only measured in Amps, so "amperage" is perfectly acceptable, and you do actually see it around the place, especially for things like fuse ratings.  Resistance is resistance is resistance.  You could use Ohmage, but no one would, because it's resistance.  Of course, the Ohm is used for other things than just resistance, like impedance, so you'd use "resistance" and "impedance" to distinguish the two, whereas Ohmage wouldn't be able to distinguish them.

Comment: In your "for instance" only the watt is a unit of power, the rest are of energy.  It is so easy to mess up.  In my opinion use the name not the unit for all but voltage.

Comment: I know "power" isn't right for joules, etc, but that doesn't stop people using it.